# Impossible to patch Account

Tags: rest-api, account, workbench, post, patch

Is there a configuration to allow patching in SalesForce ?

I tried to patch the Account on Postman, no success.
I also tried on Workbench, no success.

My Url (on workbench):

```
/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0011F00000YV8wsQAD
```

The Patch

```
{
 "AdCloud_PartnerID__c":"5400"
}
```

The Raw Response (form Workbench):

```
Raw Response
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2020 09:21:20 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains
Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin- 
sha256="blablabla"; pin- 
sha256="blablabla="; pin- 
sha256="blablabla"; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report- 
uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hpkp-report/00D1F0000009dh4m";
Expect-CT: max-age=86400, report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect- 
CT-report/00D1F0000009dh4m"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests 
X-Robots-Tag: none
Content-Length: 0
```

Why I can't Patch it ? The Error say sit is an internal error from lightning. I need to do such patch.

From Postman, PATCH + Identification with an access token :

```
https://myOrga--mySandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0011F00000YVnnwQAD
```

The headers 
    Content-Type application/json

Body raw JSON:

```
{
"AdCloud_PartnerID__c":"5400"
}
```

I get the Error :

```
500 Server Error
```

Code error :

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://orga-- 
sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account 
/0011F00000YVnnwQAD' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 00D1F000000YNnMcdT' \
--data-raw '{ "AdCloud_PartnerID__c":"5406" }'
```

Always an internal error from SalesForce...

Comment: Can you copy the "Code" from POSTMAN and show us all the headers and the HTTP method being called?

Comment: @BryanAnderson I've edited the question with more information

Comment: can you actually click on the "Code" link next to "Cookies" under the Send button and paste what is in there in your question

Comment: @BryanAnderson Thanks I didn't know that, I just post the code

Comment: If it's not working from Workbench the problem may lie within Salesforce and not anything to do with the REST API. Are you using a privileged user that can see the AdCloud_PartnerID__c field to make this update? Try changing the field on the Account record page and see if there are any errors that aren't surfacing through the REST API.

Comment: @nbrown I am the system administrator of the sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATCH seems no longer supported.
A work around is a POST method with a parameter :

```
_HttpMethod=PATCH
```

So It becomes :

```
https://orga--sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/{id}?_HttpMethod=PATCH
```

In the Body :

```
{
  "AdCloud_PartnerID__c":"5400"
}
```

Please, upvote is it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of a record update:

```
PATCH /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/001XXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
Host: myorg-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
Authorization: Bearer 00DXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "BillingCity" : "San Francisco"
}
```